# What is the safest and most convenient way to carry heavy lens so it's easy to switch in the field?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, transport, changing-lenses

## Context

I use a Nikon 300mm f4 lens. It's a good lens but it's also rather heavy.

## Question

What is the safest and most convenient way to switch teleprimes (or heavy lens in general) out in the field? I do have a [Lens Flipper](http://lensflipper.com/) but I doubt that would work well with a heavy lens. A cotton carrier is an idea but I don't know if it will work well when I sit down.

I don't have an extra body so carrying a lens on another body isn't an option.

Comment: Never head of a Lens Flipper. I gotta get me one of those! :D

Comment: Or use an old film camera; the split viewfinder can be kinda handy and you can just raise it to see if the lens will frame your shot correctly. And for manual focusing it prefocuses the lens.

Comment: I'm still waiting for science to make one of these ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_holding

Comment: Also look at the Peak Design Capture Lens clip. It can attach to your belt or rucksack strap etc. https://www.peakdesign.com/product/clips/capturelens/

Comment: The Lens Flipper looks like that's what it was *designed* for.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid They are worth using for smaller lens but if it's heavy, you'll feel it on your pants.

Comment: @WayneWerner That's not wrong but most of the weight will be on your belt or similar setup. I don't know if that's for the best.

Comment: What other lenses besides the 300m are involved? Which one is connected to the camera by default?

Comment: Pelican cases and a team of sherpas.

Comment: Currently my 300mm is my longest lens but at some point I may consider a 150-600 zoom to pair it if I want to get something to full the frame. @MichaelClark

Comment: What other lenses, of any size, are involved *now*. Which one is connected to the camera by default?

Comment: AF-S NIKKOR 300mm f/4E PF ED VR or AF-S NIKKOR 300mm f/4D IF-ED or something else?

Comment: @MichaelClark This is the older Nikon 300mm f/4 AF from 1987. By default I use a smaller Zeiss 24mm f1.8. I may consider getting a telezoom such as the Tamron 150-600.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the sound of it, you are carrying *only* a body with a lens attached and the 300mm. The camera is presumably slung over your shoulder, around your neck, or in-hand, and so you need a way to also manage the 300mm but you don't want to pull out the big camera bag, correct?

The Cotton Carrier system may be a good idea. You would need to carry/wear the vest or belt, obviously, and as you said it would likely get in the way when sitting. I don't know if it would be a concern, but it would also not offer any protection from your surroundings.

I would look at a small bag such as the [Nikon CL-M2](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/207363-REG/Nikon_4399_CL_M2_Lens_Case_Black.html) that comes with the 300, or the [Think Tank Photo Lens Changer 75](https://www.thinktankphoto.com/collections/lens-pouches/products/lens-changer-75-pop-down-v2) as a way to carry this over my shoulder (making it easy to manage when sitting and offering some protection). In fact, that's exactly what I did when carrying a 70-200 f2.8 around, which is about the same size as the 300 f4.

I moved away from that approach, though, and now use a [Think Tank Photo Skin Body Bag](https://www.thinktankphoto.com/collections/skin-pouches/products/skin-body-bag) for "light" travel because it's a little bigger and can hold a lens and flash, and has a few pockets for an extra memory card and battery.

Also, while the 300 f4 may be the biggest and heaviest lens you have, I would encourage you to just use it more to get comfortable with the weight. It's not *that* heavy and carried comfortably and as part of a larger kit I expect you would quickly get used to it.

Comment: I carry it on a shoulder strap and hold the lens. I also have a 24mm prime and might carry one more. The smaller primes are easy to pocket but I usually have to put the lens down, while shooting with another lens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the LowePro S&F Lens Exchange case. There are similar ones. They hold a long lens, and when opened produce a pouch you can place the other lens in, sort of like a bellows. You can attach the lens and detach the lens while it sits in the bag (shorter ones not so much, but they are handy for just placing on. Look at the videos to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to carry the heavy lens on the camera (a sigma 120-400, so quite heavy).  I use a modified QR plate on my camera rucksack belt to take much of the weight, and have a slightly springy strap.

My wide zoom can go in a lens pouch on the shoulder strap (the bag is a lowepro).  I tend to want the long lens ready (for wildlife) and be able to stop when I want the wide lens (landscape/macro), so this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I keep heavy lenses on my Black Rapid and keep smallers lenses in my bag.  I can quickly switch.  I toss an extra back lens cap and body cap in my bag just in case.  I think the bag I use the most is a LowePro Flipside 200.